# Sphinx: Import error in not to document package. Is there any way to "skip"?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, importerror

I am trying to start documenting an small Python project with Sphinx.

I created a `samplecode.rst` where I would try to organize (and auto-generate) the documentation for one of my classes (*MyClass.py*).

This is part of that `samplecode.rst`:

```
MyClass.py
----------------------------------
.. autoclass:: backlib.classes.MyClass
   :members:
```

But when I try to execute `make html`, I get an Import Error and the '`MyClass`' is not imported (showing an empty entry for '`MyClass`' in the generated .html):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):de                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 329, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/borrajax/Projects/myProject/backlib/classes/MyClass.py", line 4, in <module>
    from backlib.database import BaseClass
[ ... ]
    from grokcore.component import sort_components
ImportError: cannot import name sort_components
```

... and a bit later...

```
/home/borrajax/Projects/myProject/docs/source/samplecode.rst:16: (WARNING/2) autodoc can't import/find module 'backlib.classes.MyClass', it reported error: "cannot import name sort_components", please check your spelling and sys.path

/home/borrajax/Projects/myProject/docs/source/samplecode.rst:19: (WARNING/2) don't know which module to import for autodocumenting u'MyClass' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)
```

That `grokcore` thing that is messing up with my life is a module that gets installed in `$HOME/.buildout/eggs/` and that I haven't created nor I need to document.

I have added all the eggs found in `$HOME/.buildout/eggs/` to the Pythonpath (in the Sphinx's `conf.py` file) but that didn't fix anything so now I'm trying a different approach (giving up) so here goes the question: Can I do something to skip this kind of errors?

I just want the comments in `/home/borrajax/Projects/myProject/backlib/classes/MyClass.py` to show in a pretty html page, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I found the issue.

Mike Steder's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876192/289011) confirmed something that I had started suspecting by googling around: This type of *ImporErrors* in Sphinx are usually fairly trivial errors of some kind of misconfiguration. Nothing too intricate, so eventhough I had the directory where my source code was located in the `sys.path` (as Mike suggests in his answer), I started digging around.

I commenced speculating that something I had done was messing up with the PythonPath, and the only thing I had actually done was adding the `.eggs` found in `$HOME/.buildout/` through Sphinx's `conf.py` file (so there had to be something wrong with that). I checked my `$HOME/.buildout/` directory and realized that an update of the main Web Framework ([Grok](http://grok.zope.org/)) used in this project had downloaded new versions of the `.eggs` to the `$HOME/.buildout/` directory (causing most of the `.eggs` to have two versions). I removed completely the `.buildout` directory and reinstalled the Grok project (which downloaded the required .eggs, again, but now I don't have multiple versions of the same .egg).

And now, Sphinx's `make html` creates a nice entry for my `MyClass` class **:)**

Answer (score 3):

I assume your `sys.path` for in your sphinx `conf.py` doesn't include  the directory where you're source code is located.

Try adding the following to your `conf.py` for sphinx.

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/borrajax/Projects/myProject/')
```

Also, I assume `backlib` and `backlib/classes` are valid packages (they contain `__init__.py` files.).